# Manipulating the output of GIT version control system from a Java program

Tags: java, git, jgit, redirect

I am invoking the Git executable from my Java program using the process builder class and running various git commands. Java program is being run from the command prompt.
However, I'm not finding a way to extract only a particular part of the output.

Comment: What is that particular part.?

Comment: See for example after doing a commit. I use the gitdiff command to see the changes made to a repository. I only need to extract the changed part, whereas the output of gitdiff contains previous as well as current versions.

Comment: Sorry for posting ill informed statements. But that still does not answer my question.

Answer (score 0):

I would assume you use a `StreamGobbler` thread to get the input.
Just put some logic in there that filters the output.

Comment: No. I just pass the command gitdiff as an argument. Whose output I see in the gitbash/command line. 
Can u throw some light on how to filter the ouput?

Comment: What logic can be applied to filter an output which does not follow a pattern?

Answer (score 0):

like the others I would recommend the use of a java library, JGit allows many low-level operations if you need something very precise.

But maybe the Git command you are looking for is : "git diff commit_parent commit -U0" giving only the changes and no context.

You can also read the manual: "git help diff", you will find what Git offers.

But once again, I do not think it is a better idea to use a java Git library: what if the Git developers decide to change the output format tomorrow? Will you need to start over your program?